# image count / images count

Tags: grammatical-number, count

If we have a number which represents the number of images, do you call that the *images count* or the *image count*?

If you take the example with the images you could say:

> The '15' is the image count for this album

But you could also say:

> What is the minimum images count to take part in the photography competition

Which one is correct? Do you use the pluralized noun or not?

Comment: *Image count*, like *word count*, is a compound noun, so the first element stays singular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want "image count", although "images' count" has the same meaning.  You could also use "image's count" if you are counting objects in an image.  "Images count", however, only works when 'count' is a verb.